# CAT arguments: dimensions are inconsistent

Tags: string, matlab, padding, number-formatting

Kindly look at this MATLAB code:

```
formatspec = '%5i';
delay = num2str(d,formatspec);
datasave = [datasave; repeating_character blanks(5) num2str(lenmax) blanks(5) delay];
end
```

I want to display the result `datasave` in the form of a table. The variable `d` value will be incremented from `2` to `127` in a for loop. There is no problem with `lenmax` variable since it is always a single digit number. But the problem is with variable `delay`. In the first instance the value of `delay = 2`, since the loop starts with `2`, a specific dimension will be assigned to `datasave`. Then the value of `d` keeps on incrementing in the loop. During the 9<sup>th</sup> instance, it will become `10` which is a `2` digit integer. The problem is here. When it becomes a 2-digit interger (10), the dimensions will not match and error using `vertcat` comes out since the dimensions are not same.

I thought using `%5d` should solve the problem, but it doesn't. If I change loop such that it starts from `10` to `127`, the problem appears when `delay = 100`. The values from `10` to `99` will be displayed but while displaying `100`, same error about dimension mismatch pops up.

Please can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `edit num2str`, at the bottom of the main function, you'll see this (or something similar, undoubtedly depending on MATLAB version):

```
s = strtrim([cols{:}]);
```

This basically means that any white space you explicitly put in using the formatspec gets erased; a bug if you ask me.

It's easiest to use `char` to do the concatentation:

```
datasave = char(datasave, [repeating_character blanks(5) num2str(lenmax) blanks(5) delay]);
```

Alternatively, you can use `cellstrings`:

```
%# in the loop
%# (better to do this with pre-allocation) 
datasave{end+1} = [...
    repeating_character,...
    blanks(5),...
    num2str(lenmax),... 
    blanks(5),...
    delay];

...

%# after the loop
datasave = char(datasave);
```

Alternatively, you can use `int2str`:

```
delay = int2str((2:127).')
```

Alternatively, you can use `sprintf`:

```
formatspec = '%5i\n';
delay = sprintf(formatspec, 2:127)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @RodyOldenhuis explained, I think it's a subtle bug in `numstr`.

One ways to work around this is to pass the whole vector to `num2str` at once, that way white spaces are not trimmed (it's still getting trimmed, but no more than what's allowed by the longest string):

```
>> delays = num2str((2:127)', '%3d');
>> whos delays
  Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  delays      126x3               756  char    

>> delays([1 end],:)
ans =
  2
127
```

You could also choose to pad with zeros instead of spaces:

```
>> num2str(2, '%05d')
ans =
00002
```

You could also use the undocumented `sprintfc` (which returns a cell-array of untrimmed strings):

```
>> sprintfc('%5d', (2:127)')
ans = 
    '    2'
         .
         .
    '  127'
```